# How to calculate area of parallelogram given vectors

Tags: vectors, area

Find area of parallelogram that is formed using vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. It is also given that

$\vec{a} = 3\vec{p}+\vec{q}$, $\vec{b} = \vec{p}-2\vec{q}$, $|\vec{p}|=4$, $|\vec{q}|=1$, $<(p,q) = \pi / 4$

I only know that Area Of Parallelogram is equal to $|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cdot sin(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is angle between two vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: It is also equal to

$$||\vec{a}\times\vec{b}||$$

where $\times$ means the cross product.

Find cross product of $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ in terms of cross product of $\vec{p},\vec{q}$, using distributive law. Remember the fact that

$$\vec{p}\times \vec{p}=0\\
\vec{p}\times \vec{q}=-\vec{q}\times \vec{p}$$

Then when you will need to find the norm of $\vec{p}\times \vec{q}$, which is $|p| |q| \sin{\alpha}$.

Comment: @renathy: I edited the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can I just multiply (3p+q)*(p-2q) (is there any specific formula or just multiplication) and then use the formules you gave? ?

Comment: Yes, you can multiply (that is to use distributive law), just don't change the order.

Comment: It gives me -6pq+qp=7qp=7*4*1*sin(pi/4)=28*sin(pi/4) would be result?

Comment: The result is correct. But mathematically, you should write the vector signs, the cross multiplication sign, and norm (absolute value) signs appropriately. Otherwise, a vector cannot equal a scalar.